# 81 figures in a Latex document

Tags: graphics, floats

I have 81 figures saved as .png files .
I want to display them all on a Latex document .
I can plot about 10 of them before Latex starts complaining .
Here is my Latex code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\author{me}
\title{81 figures}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{...location of figure 1...png}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{...location of figure 2...png}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

then I do the following :

pdflatex file.tex (sometimes I do this 2 or 3 times to be sure but this time no cigar)

If I just do one figure then there's no problem but after I add 81 figures it complains .
! LaTeX Error: Too many unprocessed floats.

Anyone know a way around this ?
Thanks .

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: You don't need the `figure` environment to include images, so you could just place all the `\includegraphics` commands in a  single `center` environment instead, as you're not adding captions.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't 19 figures when LaTeX starts complaining, supposedly with `! LaTeX Error: Too many unprocessed floats.`?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured it out all on my lonelies .

Seemingly Latex was confused on how to place all these figures .
I wanted two figures per page so all I had to do was type

```
\clearpage
```

after every two figures .
But then I noticed that some of the pages only had one figure .
It turns out that sometimes I had

```
figure.png}
```

and sometimes I had

```
figure.png }
```

with a space between the png and the parenthesis. After getting rid of the space for each one , everything worked out perfectly. 81 figures, 2 on each page and one on the last page . :)